# Can't figure out for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a secret coding program but am having trouble with for loops (I've never really understood them). Here is what I have to far, I'm trying to get the users input, the convert each word of the users text into the coded text, so if someone types in "hello", it will become "vpyyl". Can someone please help? Is this even possible?

This is what I have so far, it's giving an error "list indices must be integers, not str". I'm pretty sure the for loop is set up wrong as well.

```
import random

list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
codedList = ['s', 'q', 'n', 'z', 'p', 'o', 'k', 'v', 'm', 'c', 'i', 'y', 'w', 'a', 'l', 't', 'd', 'r', 'j', 'b', 'f', 'e', 'h', 'u', 'x', 'g']

text = input("Enter your text: ")

for i in [text]:
    i = codedList[i]
    print[i]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's only one item in `[text]`: the whole string that was entered by the user. You probably want `for i in text:` which will set `i` to each character of the string.

Also, you've named a list `list` (which means you've lost access to the built-in name `list`). And lists are indexed by integers, while you're trying to access the elements with a string. You probably want to use a dictionary for that, mapping each letter to its coded equivalent.

A couple of other problems are that you don't have any code to handle situations in which something other than a letter is entered (spaces, punctuation) and the letters are all lowercase. Finally, you're using square brackets in your `print` call instead of parentheses, and you're not suppressing line breaks.

So:

```
code = dict(a='s', b='q', c='n', d='z', e='p', f='o', g='k', h='v', i='m', j='c',
            k='i', l='y', m='w', n='a', o='l', p='t', q='d', r='r', s='j', t='b',
            u='f', v='e', w='h', x='u', y='x', z='g')

# another way to define the dictionary (you don't need both)
alphabet      = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
codedalphabet = "sqnzpokvmciywaltdrjbfehuxg"
code          = dict(zip(alphabet, codedalphabet))

# add upper-case versions of all letters to dictionary
for letter, codedletter in code.iteritems():
    code[letter.upper()] = codedletter.upper()

for char in input("Enter your text: "):
    if char in code:
        print(code[char], end="")
    else:
        print(char, end="")    # not an alphabetic character, print as-is
print()                        # we haven't printed a line break; do so now
```

As others have noted, there are some things built into Python that can make this trivial, but if you're having trouble with `for` loops, that won't help you learn.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

In Python, before you start programming anything, check if there's a built-in function that does the same. With probability 90% there is.

```
chars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
coded = ['s', 'q', 'n', 'z', 'p', 'o', 'k', 'v', 'm', 'c', 'i', 'y', 'w', 'a', 'l', 't', 'd', 'r', 'j', 'b', 'f', 'e', 'h', 'u', 'x', 'g']

table = str.maketrans(chars, coded)
coded_text = text.translate(table)

print (coded_text)
```

Documentation:  [translate](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html?#str.translate) | [maketrans](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html?#str.maketrans)

Comment: +1 In practice, between the standard library and NumPy, I use a lot fewer for-loops in Python than in C.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in [text]:
```

should be

```
for i in text:
```

and `i` in your case is a character of the string user input-ed..

it should be an integer to work as index

The code you intent should be like..

Note : I have used raw_input instead of input, 
since input would try to `eval` user input you will end up with and `NameError` error

```
In [214]: import random

In [215]: mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

In [216]: codedList = ['s', 'q', 'n', 'z', 'p', 'o', 'k', 'v', 'm', 'c', 'i', 'y', 'w', 'a', 'l', 't', 'd', 'r', 'j', 'b', 'f', 'e', 'h', 'u', 'x', 'g']

In [217]: text = raw_input("Enter your text: ")
Enter your text: hello

In [218]: str = []

In [219]: for i in text:
   .....:     j = mylist.index(i)
   .....:     str.append(codedList[j])
   .....:

In [220]: ''.join(str)
Out[220]: 'vpyyl'
```

And as for the `for loop` , text contains the word 'hello', 
the for loop here will iterate every character in the text i.e. first iteration will be over 'h', then 'e' and so on.

the name of the list should never be `list`, as this name is keyword in python

Answer (score 2):

There a number of different ways to accomplish what you are trying to do. but focusing on what you have already started and your current code (with some identifiers changed for readability/clarity), then given:

```
clearList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
codedList = ['s', 'q', 'n', 'z', 'p', 'o', 'k', 'v', 'm', 'c', 'i', 'y', 'w', 'a', 'l', 't', 'd', 'r', 'j', 'b', 'f', 'e', 'h', 'u', 'x', 'g']

text = input("Enter your text: ")
```

Your `for`-loop should look like this:

```
for letter in text:            # iterate over the text not [text]
   idx = clearList.index(letter)  # find the index for the given letter in clearList
   print(codedList[idx], end="")  # get the corresponding coded letter with the index
```

and results in `vpyyl`.

***Note***, it is not a good idea to have *list* as an identifier, Python already uses it for the name of the data structure. I also used a more descriptive identifier for your `letter` of your input.

--

Since you mentioned having problems with `for`-loops, here are two tutorials for you:
From the Python [Wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) and this one form [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_for_loop.htm).

Comment: @NoobMcNoobNoob My updated answer also contains links to some tutorials on `for`-loops since you mentioned that they are giving you problems.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1. You are using `i` as both the iteration variable and to hold the encoded-value. This one is harmless, but bad practice.
2. You are iterating over a single-element array contain text as its one element. Remove the `[]` around `text`:

   ```
   for i in text:
       print codedList[i]
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to encode your string with another alphabet.

In your code,

```
for i in [text]:
    i = codedList[i]
    print[i]
```

You should find the index of the 'i' in original list through the .index().
A workable revision code as below.

```
for i in text:
    index = list.index(i)
    i = codedList[index]
    print [i]
```